SQL Server Authentication failing when running SSMS using runas \netonly
I use the runas \netonly command to launch SSMS as another Windows user that has elevated database permissions. This is so I can retain access to the local drives / directories that my normal user (but not my 'db admin' user) can access. I don't seem to then be able to connect to other sql server instances using sql server authentication. I've tested the same sql login connects successfully when SSMS is launched without runas \netonly. The Connect to server window disappears after I click Connect as if it is going to work, but then nothing happens.
Please can anyone confirm if it is possible to use sql server authentication when using the runas \netonly command to launch SSMS?
It looks like the culprit is the Remember password check box. It doesn't work when this is ticked, but does when it isn't. So the question is partly answered, but is it possible to get ssms to connect using sql server authentication and remember passwords when runas \netonly ?



I have tested using the same options in a session of ssms launched without the runas \netonly command and they work.
